# pthread_join fails in forking TCP server when handling multiple clients

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I have to create a multithread TCP/IP server which contains a variable to count the number of clients connected (and those which disconnect) and print the number of clients connected when a client connects to the server.

This is my *client.c* file:

```
#define PORT 4444

int main ()
{
    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    char buffer[1024];
    ssize_t nread;

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket == -1) {
        perror("[-]Errore durante la creazione della socket\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("[+]Client socket has been created\n");


    memset(&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) == -1) {
        perror("Errore con la connessione\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {

        printf("> ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", buffer);

        if (nread != -1)
            buffer[nread] = '\0';*/

        if (send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Errore con l'invio");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0) {
            close(clientSocket);
            printf("[-]Disconnected from Server\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        if ( (nread=recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1, 0)) <= 0) {
            perror("[-]Error in receiving data from server\n");
        }
        else {
            buffer[nread] = '\0';
            printf("Server received: %s\n", buffer);
        }

    }

    close(clientSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my *server.c* file:

```
#define PORT 4444
#define MAX_CONNESSIONI 100

typedef struct myStruct {
    int clientCollegati;
    int clientCheSiSonoScollegati;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex; // Creazione del mutex per sincronizzare la struttura
} myStruct;

myStruct *test; 

myStruct *initStruct();
void *incrementa(void*);

int main ()
{
    int serverSocket, bindStatus;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddress;
    char buffer[1024];
    pid_t child;
    socklen_t addrSize;
    ssize_t nread;
    pthread_t tid;

    test = initStruct(); 

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, incrementa, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("Errore nella creazione del thread t1\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket == -1) {
        perror("[-]Errore durante la creazione della socket\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    memset(&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bindStatus = bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    if (bindStatus == -1) {
        perror("[-]Errore durante il binding\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Bind to port %d\n", PORT);


    if (listen(serverSocket, MAX_CONNESSIONI) != -1) {
        printf("Listening . . .\n\n");
    }
    else {
        perror("[-]Error during listening\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while (1) {

        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddress, &addrSize);
        if (clientSocket == -1) {
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("%s:%d joined\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port));

        if (pthread_join(tid, NULL)) { // returns 3
            perror("pthread_join error\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("There is/are %d client(s) connected\n", test->clientCollegati);

        child = fork();
        if (child == 0) {

            close(serverSocket);

            while (1) {

                if ( (nread=recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1, 0)) <= 0) {
                    perror("[-]Error in receiving data from server\n");
                }
                else {
                    buffer[nread] = '\0';
                }


                if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0) {
                    printf("%s:%d left\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port));
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s:%d wrote: %s\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port), buffer);
                    send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }

            }

        }

    }

    close(clientSocket);

    return 0;
}

myStruct *initStruct()
{
    struct myStruct *ptr = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));

    ptr->clientCollegati = 0;
    ptr->clientCheSiSonoScollegati = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&ptr->mutex, NULL); // inizializzazione dinamica del mutex

    return ptr;

}

void *incrementa(void *ptr)
{

    pthread_mutex_lock(&test->mutex); 


    test->clientCollegati++;


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&test->mutex);

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

Unfortunately this seems not to work properly, ans you can see [server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZImqB.png) and here [client1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nePsi.png) and here [client2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjWYl.png)

- Where's the mistake? I suppose that the problem is when tid finish and a second call to that `pthread_join` is invoked to a non-existent thread (because there is a single thread)

Comment: What's the error code returned by pthread_join?

Comment: Do you know what threads *do*?

Comment: It returns 3...

Comment: What is strerror(3)?

Comment: I've edited your question title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code logic is wrong. You are doing a single `pthread_create()` and then multiple `pthread_join()`. If you want to increment the values for every connected client you have to do one `pthread_create()` after every single successful `accept()`, followed by one `pthread_join()`. Note: all this must happen *before* the call to `fork()`.

> Where's the mistake? I suppose that the problem is when `tid` finish and a second call to that `pthread_join` is invoked to a non-existent thread (because there is a single thread)

That's exactly what happens. In your current program, the first `pthread_join()` is successful, and any successive call fails with errno 3 (no such process) because the thread doesn't exist anymore. So you already figured this out. Why are you creating one thread but joining it multiple times if you know that's wrong?

The way your program is written (fork after the increment) also means that there really is no reason at all to use threads to do the increment, and you don't even need the mutex, since only one single thread will access the value at any given time. In other words, your server isn't multithreaded at all. If you only want to do this as an experiment that's ok, but it doesn't make much sense.

What you probably want to do (to have a multithreaded server) is to have *one thread per client* instead of forking each time, with the client code in the thread function (in that case having a mutex makes sense). Beware though that this does not scale well for large numbers of clients (in general, the classical `fork()` approach is better, in which case you really don't need any thread).

Comment: fork() approach is not the best because creating a process (in the PID sense) is more demanding in terms of system resources (especially memory), without forgetting the cost of copying data from the parent process, ... a multithreaded approach remains lighter and therefore more efficient. Opting for a fork-based approach should be justified by constraints that cannot be satisfied in multithreaded mode

Comment: @Landstalker a multithreaded approach is hardly used in reality, because provides no isolation from the server process, because threads are scheduled differently than processes, and most importantly because system limits like for example the number of open file descriptors per process can be easily exceeded. A forking server that `fork()`s right after `accept()` and executes a different (lighter) client process is the de-facto standard way of implementing multi-client TCP servers. That's the point I was trying to make. Of course multithreading *can* still be useful depending on the scenario.

Comment: If you are looking for a SIMPLE solution, fork is the best approach because the memory spaces are separated by default (different heap, different stack, ...)
However, if you are looking for performance, optimization of system resources, ... multithreading is more suitable (but more complicated management).
you just have to compare the time of a FORK compared to create_thread, plus the quantity of monopolized resources ... the use of the fork must be justified according to the need. before opting for the fork, you have to ask yourself the question, does multithreading allow me to do this?